# MADE and MSE pros and cons

Tags: estimators, mse

When assessing the performance of an estimator, in which scenarios should one prefer the use of the **Mean Absolute Deviation Error** (MADE) over the **Mean Squared Error** (MSE) and vice versa?

Edit / Clarification:

Assume that we have i.i.d data $(X_{1},Y_{1}),\cdots,(X_{n},Y_{n})$. Let $(X,Y)$ denote a generic member of the sample who's conditional mean is denoted by $m(x)=E(Y|X=x)$.

The performance of an estimator $\hat{m}(x)$ of $m(x)$ is often assessed either by:

$$MSE(x)=E\left[\left\{ \hat{m}(x)-m(x)\right\} ^{2}|\boldsymbol{X}\right]$$

or by

$$MADE(x)=E\left[\left|\hat{m}(x)-m(x)\right||\boldsymbol{X}\right]$$
 where $\mathbf{X}=(X_{1},\cdots,X_{n}).$

Comment: Are you speaking of **median** absolute deviation?

Comment: @ttnphns No. **Mean** absolute deviation error.